# Font that makes Arabic and English look of a similar size when set to the same font size

Tags: html, css, fonts, arabic

I am developing a website that support both English and Arabic. The problem is that when I use a specific font size, English looks bigger that Arabic. I know how I can work this out using CSS but if there are fonts that overcome this by default that would save time and make future updates easy.

Comment: This seems to be asking for help in finding a font with some properties. That would be off-topic at SO. But it is difficult to see what the question is. Arabic letters may give the impression of being smaller than Latin letters, but this is common font design, and deviating from it would create a problem (due to its being uncommon) rather than solve one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're using multi-lingual fonts such as "Arial".

For your question I looked at Google Translate since they have same font size for all languages.
They are using there the following line as "font-family"

```
"arial,sans-serif!important".
```

Take notice that letters' width and height may vary between languages and may cause the feeling of "smaller letters".

hope that helps :)
glhf

Comment: Yeah correct! it feels smaller as you explained. if Google does not care about that then I should not worry. I will use the same font size for both.thank you.

Comment: I don’t see how this answers the question. Rather, it seems to say that it is not a problem, but then it should be a comment, not an answer. And in Arial, the size difference between Latin and Arabic letters tends to be *larger* than many other fonts, like Times New Roman.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the "Coranica" font provided by [this](http://www.corpuscoranicum.de/) Arabic research project, which was developed especially for the case you described:

http://www.corpuscoranicum.de/fonts/coranica_allerseelen2012_09.ttf